# p:dataTable does not Read From Database Issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I had a school project this past semester building a web application with a database for a section of Habitat for Humanity. I was able to connect and write to the database just fine, but I had trouble reading the data that was in the database and placing it into a Primefaces DataTable.

I will add my Java Class to read from the database below, as well as my HTML that has my variables for the DataTable.

If someone can take a look at my code and see if they find any mistakes or have any hints/tips, it would be much appreciated. The class is over now, but I want to be able to try and figure out the rest of the web application to get it fully up and running, instead of just leaving it in the past. Any help would be appreciated!

UserDAO - Java Class:

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import model.UserBean;

/**
 * @author rnikolich
 */
public class UserDAO {

String driverName = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
String connStr = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/HabitatDatabase";
public static ArrayList<UserBean> getOwners() {
ArrayList<UserBean> ownerCollection = new ArrayList<>();
Connection DBConn = null;
try {
        DBHelper.loadDriver("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        String myDB = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/HabitatDatabase";
        DBConn = DBHelper.connect2DB(myDB, "test", "test");
//            UserBean usr = new UserBean();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM HABITATDATABASE.OWNER";

        // With the connection made, create a statement to talk to the DB 
server.
        // Create a SQL statement to query, retrieve the rows one by one (by 
going to the
        // columns), and formulate the result string to send back to the 
client.
        Statement stmt = DBConn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
//            Timestamp timestamp;
//            Vote aVote;
        while (rs.next()) {
            UserBean own = new UserBean();
            own.setOwnerID(rs.getString("OwnerID"));
            own.setOwnerName(rs.getString("OwnerName"));
            own.setPhone(rs.getString("Phone"));
            own.setEmail(rs.getString("Email"));


// or rs.getString("PL_Name");
//                timestamp = rs.getTimestamp("vote_TimeStamp");
//
//                // make a VoteTally object out of the values
//                aVote = new Vote(PL_Name, timestamp);
            // add the newly created object to the collection
            ownerCollection.add(own);
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: Problems with SQL select");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        DBConn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return ownerCollection;
}
}
```

usersController - Java Class:

```
package controller;

import dao.UserDAO;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import model.UserBean;
import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UsersController implements Serializable {

    private UserBean theModel;
    private ArrayList<UserBean> owner;

    /**
     * *
     */
 public ArrayList<UserBean> getOwner() {
        UserDAO own = new UserDAO();
        owner = UserDAO.getOwners();
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(ArrayList<UserBean> owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of UsersController
     */
    public UsersController() {
        theModel = new UserBean();
    }

    public UserBean getTheModel() {
        return theModel;
    }

    public void setTheModel(UserBean theModel) {
        this.theModel = theModel;
    }
}
```

viewOwner - XHTML:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>View Owner</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
              integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
    </h:head>
    <h:body style="background-color: gray">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="container">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="row centered-form">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-1"
                              style="background-color: limegreen">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="panel panel-default">
                        <center><h:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:habitat-for-humanity-logo.jpg']}" width="200" height="180"/></center>                   
                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="panel-heading">
                            <center><h3 class="panel-title">View Owner</h3></center>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <br></br>
                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="panel-body">
                            <h:form id="viewOwnerForm">
                                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="form-group">                                

                                    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

                                    <p:dataTable id="viewOwnerDataTable" value="#{usersController.owner}" var="o" rows="10"> 

                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            View Owners Table
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <p:column headerText="OwnerID">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{o.ownerID}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column headerText="OwnerName">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{o.ownerName}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column headerText="Phone">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{o.phone}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column headerText="Email">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{o.email}" />
                                        </p:column>  

                                    </p:dataTable>

                                    <br></br>

                                    <h:commandLink>
                                        <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:pdf.png']}" width="24"/>
                                        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="owners"/>
                                    </h:commandLink>

                                    <br></br>
                                    <br></br>
                                    <h:link outcome="home" value="Home" styleClass="btn btn-warning btn-block" id="Home" style="background-color: blue"/>
                                    <h:link outcome="viewHome" value="View Entry Home" styleClass="btn btn-warning btn-block" id="viewHome" style="background-color: blue"/>
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </h:form>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's really difficult to say what (or how many) problems there are. You didn't provide the whole class, you said nothing about the environment you use to run this application. Seeing the main method in you Java class makes me wonder whether you have your class properly annotated.

Comment: Don't mix namespaces for different JSF versions. And the `getOwners` is nowhere used in the xhtml... Please learn (your teacher should have told you this) to make a [mcve] when troubleshooting... 99% of the cases are not both jsf and database related, and even less to netbeans (or the IDE in general).

Comment: Please [mcve] as requested before. 'whole' Classes is wrong... An mcve helps you narrow down the problem

Comment: @Kukeltje I have not had a teacher show us that or even bring it up in class, but I will take a look at that and consider starting over. Thank you for attaching the link.

Comment: @OndřejXichtSvětlík I added the rest of my Java class, as well as added another supporting java class. I am using Netbeans with a JSF application. I am also using a Primefaces DataTable plugin for some different attributes on the project.

Comment: And what was the problem? The getter was not called or did it throw some exception, there are really too many possibilities. Did you try to debug it?